# Rewrite rule to remove .php extension using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I have found many solutions on StackOverflow to handle this common problem but none seem to work for my setup. When I link to a php page I still see the .php extension and would like to have

```
index.php updated to 'website'

about-us.php to be website/about
```

I am working on a site using wamp / localhost inside a folder 'website'. I have my .htacces file located inside the root of the 'website' folder.

The rewrite condition / rule I'm trying to use to remove the .php extension from index.php and other php pages is this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

My links have URL's like this

```
<a href="index.php">
<a href="about-us.php">
```

Here's the full .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Comment: here you can directly link to `index` instead of `index.php` `<a href="index">` use this.

Comment: @ Abhishek. Thanks. Yeah we know about that one use-case but curious how to fix on all pages with .php extensions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually "removing" `.php` from the URL, it works as redirecting.
In other words, if you don't want others see that `.php` in your URL, then you'll have to fix all your link.

i.e `<a href='www.example.com'>`

`<a href='www.example.com/about-us'>`

`<a href='www.example.com/blog'>`

You'll have to fix all your links inside your script.